# Doing a json put request saves unedited field as blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

In my Rails app I have made an api for an iOS app to consume.

I have a `user` model with a association to a `profile`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :personal_profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :personal_profile
end

class PersonalProfile < Profile
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The `users_controller.rb` looks like this:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < Api::V1::ApiController
  before_filter :authenticate_api_user, only: [:show, :update]

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user
    else
      render json: { errors: @user.errors.full_messages }, status: 422
    end
  end

  def show
    @user
  end

  def update
    if @user.update(user_params)
      @user
    else
      render json: { errors: @user.errors.full_messages }, status: 422
    end
  end

private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :birthday, :gender, :password, :password_confirmation, personal_profile_attributes: [:website, :location, :description, :tagline, :tag_tokens, :image, :image_cache])
  end

  def authenticate_api_user
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|     
      @user = User.find_by(auth_token: token)
    end
  end
end
```

When I do a put request like this:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Token token=AUTH_TOKEN' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X PUT -d '{"user": {"name": "Frank", "personal_profile_attributes": { "tagline": "New tagline" }}}' http://localhost:3000/api/user
```

I get this response:

```
{"errors":["Personal profile title can't be blank."]}
```

And it's like the server doesn't recognize my params:

```
Started PUT "/api/user" for ::1 at 2016-01-19 10:16:33 +0100
Processing by Api::V1::UsersController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"name"=>"Frank", "personal_profile_attributes"=>{"tagline"=>"New tagline"}}}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."auth_token" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["auth_token", AUTH_TOKEN]]
   (0.8ms)  BEGIN
  PersonalProfile Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."type" IN ('PersonalProfile') AND "profiles"."user_id" = $1  ORDER BY title asc LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
  SQL (1.3ms)  UPDATE "profiles" SET "user_id" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "profiles"."id" = $3  [["user_id", nil], ["updated_at", "2016-01-19 09:16:33.629907"], ["id", 1]]
  User Exists (1.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('d@friis.me') AND "users"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
   (0.8ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 19ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 6.5ms)
```

I have another controller setup for the web app, which is pretty standard and works just fine!

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like your model `Profile` has validation `validate_presence_of :title` or like this. Model `PersonalProfile` inherited from `Profile` and has the same validations as base model.

Comment: @Sema yes, but the `title` is already set, and I'm not updating it in the request.

Comment: may be a profile record persisted for the user does not have any title (for example, record was persisted before validation was implemented in source code). What is returned by `Profile.find(1).title` from rails console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the problem was that I did not pass an `ID` for the associated record with the request params. This meant that a new associated record was created with the attributes I was trying to update.

Setting the `ID` solved the problem and updated the record as expected.

```
{ 
  "user" => { 
    "personal_profile_attributes" => {
      "id" => 1,
      "tagline" => "New tagline"
    }
  }
}
```